# Java for loop returning "Index Out Of Bounds" Error

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to solve this prompt where you have to detect whether a sentence is a pangram or not. I'm getting an error on line 8 and line 20, saying 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 26 out of bounds for length 26.' I am really confused why this error is occurring. Can someone help, I've tried searching this error up. Sorry if my code is really bad, This is my 10th day of Java.

```
public class Solution {

  public static boolean check(String sentence){
    boolean[] validLetter = new boolean[26];
    System.out.println(validLetter.length);
    for (int i=0; i <= sentence.length(); i++) {
      if ('a' <= sentence.charAt(i) && sentence.charAt(i) <= 'z') {
        validLetter[i] = true;
      }
      else validLetter[i] = false;
    }
    for (int i=0; i <= validLetter.length; i++) {
      if (validLetter[i] == false) return false;
    }
    return true;
    
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Solution.check("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `for (int i=0; i < sentence.length(); i++)` in your iterations and not `<=`.

I'd suggest looking into how to iterate arrays in Java
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterating-arrays-java/

Answer (score 0):

Array in java and most of programming languages start the index from **0**, so when your array length/size is 26 you can access it by `array[25]`.

Please read the documentations :)

[Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)